# onImageAvailable function returning wrong image size

Tags: java, android

I am using ImageReader class to handle getting images from my camera app but I've been getting the wrong image size compared to the size I fed when initializing it.

However, this is only happening in my **Samsung Galaxy Note 5**. My code works with my other test phones (Huawei Nova 2i, LG G6, Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge).

I'm initializing my ImageReader with this code:

```
ImageReader.newInstance(1440,1080,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
```

The input dimensions were obtained from the code below so I know 1440x1080 is supported by the Note 5.

```
final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
final StreamConfigurationMap map =  characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
// map returns all supported dimensions
```

Other dimensions with the 4:3 ratio smaller than 1440x1080 returns images with the same dimensions. But when it comes to that size, the image that I get is 1440x1440, a 1:1 ratio. Why?

```
@Override
    public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

            System.out.println("===image" + image.getWidth() + "x" + image.getHeight());
            //===image1440x1440



            if (image == null) {
                return;
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception!", e);
            Trace.endSection();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a question here you'd like answered? If so, please make it explicit.

Comment: I want to know why this is happening, or if there is a fix for this.